# Power Meter - Cocos2d/Box2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

How would I create a power meter that shoots a ball in the direction and power chosen by the player?

I also have a button that will "fire" the ball.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's not clear what a "power meter" is. If it "shoots", it probably should not be called "meter", but "gun" or "cannon". Adding an screenshot of what you want might also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but maybe you can look at `CCProgressTimer`. With this you can set the percent of the image you want to show (using a horizontal type for your standard progress bar - or whatever).

The code that you need is:

`timer.type = kCCProgressTimerTypeHorizontalBarLR;`

`timer.percentage = 0; //of whatever percent you want to show (you need to update this manually)`